# Transform a while loop with counter into a more pythonic code

Tags: python, while-loop

Is there a way to trasform this python code into a more pythonic one?

```
i = 0
while condition:
    doSomething()
    i+=1
```

Comment: Depends. What is `condition`, and how do you use `i`? Do you just want to count, how often the loop was executed?

Comment: Its quite difficult to explain. The condition is boolean and its value depends on what dosomething() will perform. Dosomething() is a method that changes its behavior on the base of what other concurrent methods and instances will perform. (It's all managed through a discrete event simulator)

Comment: That's already as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: There's nothing really unPythonic about what you've done.  A while loop is generally used when you don't know at the time the loop is initiated how long it will have to run (or, rather, at least the maximum number of iterations).  If you want to continue to do something until some condition becomes false, you've accomplished that in a perfectly acceptable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `count` for this type.

```
from itertools import count
c = count(0)
while condition:
    doSomething()
    next(c) # returns 0, +1 in further loops
```

But if you know how much loops you want, Try `for loop`.

```
for i in range(n):
    doSomething()
```

Comment: You can't use the counter in your loop if you need to doing it that way.

Comment: @JeromeJ why cant use counter here ?

Comment: `c` being the `itertools.count` object, what I mean by counter is what is returned by `next(c)` so to use that in your loop you would need to put `i = next(c)` at the beginning of your loop. It's just a small detail.

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is about the value of i like "i < 10", you can use "for" statement:

```
for i in range (10):
    do_something ()
```

This will execute the function 10 times.

Comment: I think the intent was to `doSomething()` as long as `condition` is `True`, and track how many times it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

To second [itzmeontv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29287714/1524913), I personally do this:

```
for i in itertools.count():
    if not condition:
        break

    do_something()
```

***Note:** Infinite loops are usually to be avoided if possible but, you know what's worse? Manual counters. Especially if they are at the bottom of the loop. That's why I put the condition check at the very top, right under the `for` loop statement.*

However, if you know how many iterations you need, you can just use:

```
for i in range(100):
   do_something()
```

And replace `100` by the desired amount of iterations.